# Using Smarty to strip P tags from my HTML

Tags: php, smarty, paragraph, strip-tags

I'm using this code `{$entry.entry|strip_tags}` to strip tags, however I would just like to strip `<p>` tags and **not all HTML tags**.

Can someone help?

Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to strip *ONLY* `<p>` tags, try a simple regular-expression replacement:

```
{$entry.entry|regex_replace:"/(<p>|<p [^>]*>|<\\/p>)/":""}
```

This will replace `<p>`, `</p>` and all `<p many attributes>` strings with an empty string.

Let me know if it works. I tested the regular expression in PHP, not directly in Smarty.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the [regex_replace](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl) modifier:

```
{$foo = '<p>hello world</p><p some-att="ribute">foo</p>'}
{$foo|regex_replace:'#<\s*/?\s*p(\s[^>]*)?>#i':' '|escape}
```